# Is there an option for Oracle SQL Developer so that query results with new lines are not embedded in quotes after copy-pasting?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When I try to copy the value of a single cell of a query result that contains new lines, the text is embedded in quotes:

For example, if I execute this simple query:

```
select 'foo' || chr(10) || 'bar' baz from dual;
```

and copy paste the (only) returned value and paste it into a text document, it appears as

```
"foo
bar"
```

(with the quotes). I'd rather not have the quotes. Is there a setting or option I am missing to change this behavior?

Comment: i'm not sure why we're putting it in double quotes in addition to the single quotes, I think that bit is a bug

Comment: If you could use your influence on changing this, I, for one, would certainly be very grateful.

Comment: I logged a bug for you @René-Nyffenegger

Comment: i've just cancelled the bug, we purposely put in the double quotes because of the new line, removing these would break things in other places

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time you took, I do appreciate it - although this feature still bugs me :-)

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, at least you have work arounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy and paste from the Single Record View, you'll just get the 'raw text'

[image]